# Passing data between Activity and View class

Tags: java, android, class

In my android application, I need to pass some data from an Activity class to a View class. But the problem is, I cannot call

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

method in View class. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You don't "pass data" to a `View` class using the extras of an `Intent` in the same way you'd start an `Activity`. The `Activity` class is basically a UI framework and as such has direct access to all of its 'views'. If you've created a custom `View` then simply add a public method to it which allows passing of whatever data you need. The `Activity` then simply needs to use `findViewById(...)` to get the instance of the 'view' and call the public method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Extends `View` Class

1) Declare variable

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
```

2) Put This Method

```
public void setData(Bundle data)
{
   bundle =data;
}
```

Access from Activity

```
View mView =new View(YourActivity.this);

mView.setData(new Bundle());
```

Comment: I need to access data from View class to some drawings.

Comment: make your view class an inner class of your activity class